# Cannot programmatically perform segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard segue with an identifier that is 'Push to ResumeView'.

I try calling it in the ViewController that I'm in at the point, by doing

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Push to ResumeView" sender: self];`.

But nothing happens?

I'd much rather just push the ViewController using the top NavigationController or something, but I can't see how to do that either.

Comment: Just use your nav controller like you said, [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: Show me screenshot of your story board and check your identifier, better use proper naming convention of identifier instead of using space

Comment: @"Push to ResumeView" : remove spaces in your identifier

Comment: I changed the name, heres a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/LgQIl3G.png

Comment: Also, here is that part of my code, this line is the one where I try to call the push view controller. I think the problem is I'm using `self.navigationController` instead of the top navigationController, as defined in the storyboard. So thats why it isn't doing anything. But I'm not sure https://github.com/AndrewSB/wwdc-scholarship-app/blob/master/FBCall/FBAppViewController.m#L81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` or `prepareForSegue:sender:` methods in the 'from' view controller. Put a break point or NSLog() inside the method to inspect the segue identifier. This will prove that you indeed set up the segue correctly in the storyboard.

If you want to manually push your next view controller to the top of the navigation controller, use `pushViewController:animated:`. However, if you are using storyboard, the preferred way is to use segues.

Comment: I added a `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` with an NSLog in it an it didn't fire. So I think there's a problem with how I'm doing the segue? Here's that line https://github.com/AndrewSB/wwdc-scholarship-app/blob/master/FBCall/FBAppViewController.m#L79

Comment: Hmm... I think you just never call `pushresume` :)

Comment: But the NSLog at the top of the method, that outputs push resume, is in my console. So I know the method gets called

Comment: Try implementing `prepareForSegue:sender:`. I forgot that `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` doesn't get called when you trigger the segue programmatically.

Comment: implemented in the ViewController, it didn't breakpoint... So am I not calling the segue?

Comment: I really don't see you are calling `pushResume`. Try calling it somewhere in your view controller to see if it breaks or not.

Comment: Yea, I put a break inside the method, it breaks

Comment: I found my error, I'm calling the `pushResume` method from an instance of the vc I created inside a NSObject.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to call the method without creating an instance. This is where I create the instance and call the method https://github.com/AndrewSB/wwdc-scholarship-app/blob/master/FBCall/FBFacebookRequests.m#L88

Comment: You don't want to call `alloc-init` to initialize a view controller in a storyboard. All view controllers in a storyboard are instantiated when it is loaded. Instead, you should grab the view controller using UIStoryboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method. You need to give an identifier for the view controller in the storyboard ID field in the Identity Inspector (Cmd-Opt-3).

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue:sender:` to make sure execution reaches there.

Comment: I figured it out, I was just creating a new instance of the view and trying to call it from there. Really stupid mistake

Comment: "All view controllers in a storyboard are instantiated when it is loaded" -- no, that's not true. Only the initial view controller, and it's children (and any of the child's root views if they have them) are instantiated at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
UIViewController *yourResumeView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PushToResumeView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourResumeView animated:YES];
```